# Re-Link to new mdb then delete old database (mdb)

Tags: ms-access

I have a procedure where the ultimate objective is to update all tables on a server backend database from a laptop.  Once this is complete, I want to delete the local (laptop) mdb and replace the deleted file (mdb) with the server mdb.

All seems to work well except I can't delete the local version even though I have re-linked the laptop front end to the server backend.  Here is my code:

```
Call CloseALLFormsReports
  Call RelinkTables("K:\Proposals\Northway\Data\Northway Data.accdb")

 ****************************************** 
  'backup current c: database
  tBackupfile = "C:\Proposals\backup\Northway DATA" & Format(Now(), "yyyymmdd hhmm") & ".accdb"
  Call TransferBEData("C:\Proposals\Northway DATA.accdb", tBackupfile)
  'now overwrite c:drive file
    Call TransferBEData("K:\Proposals\Northway\Data\Northway Data.accdb", "C:\Proposals\Northway DATA.accdb")
    Call RelinkTables("C:\Proposals\Northway DATA.accdb")

*************HERE IS THE TransferBEDate function:
Function TransferBEData(ByVal tSource As String, ByVal tDestination As String)

If FileExists(tDestination) Then
  Kill tDestination
End If

FileCopy tSource, tDestination

End Function

************HERE IS MY Relinking Function
Public Sub RelinkTables(strNewPath As String)

Dim dbs As DAO.Database
Dim tdf As TableDef
Dim intCount As Integer
Dim frmCurrentForm As Form
Dim relink As Boolean

DoCmd.Hourglass True
On Error GoTo ErrLinkUpExit
'Me.lblMsg.Visible = True
'Me.cmdOK.Enabled = False

Set dbs = CurrentDb

For intCount = 0 To dbs.TableDefs.Count - 1
Set tdf = dbs.TableDefs(intCount)
If tdf.Connect <> "" Then
'Me.lblMsg.Caption = "Refreshing " & tdf.Name
DoEvents
tdf.Connect = ";DATABASE=" & strNewPath
tdf.RefreshLink
End If ' tdf.Connect <> ""
Next intCount

Set dbs = Nothing
Set tdf = Nothing

DoCmd.Hourglass False
 MsgBox ("The file:  " & strNewPath & " was successfully linked.")
'Me.lblMsg.Caption = "All Links were refreshed!"
relink = True
'Me.cmdOK.Enabled = True
Exit Sub

ErrLinkUpExit:
DoCmd.Hourglass False

Select Case Err
Case 3031 ' Password Protected
 MsgBox "Back End '" & strNewPath & "'" & " is password protected"
Case 3011 ' Table missing
DoCmd.Hourglass False
 MsgBox "Back End does not contain required table '" & _
  tdf.SourceTableName & "'"
Case 3024 ' Back End not found
 MsgBox "Back End Database '" & strNewPath & "'" & " " & _
  "Not Found"
Case 3051 ' Access Denied
 MsgBox "Access to '" & strNewPath & "' Denied " & _
 vbCrLf & _
 " May be Network Security or Read Only Database"
Case 3027 ' Read Only
 MsgBox "Back End '" & strNewPath & "'" & " is Read " & _
 "Only "
Case 3044 ' Invalid Path
 MsgBox strNewPath & " Is Not a Valid Path"
Case 3265
 MsgBox "Table '" & tdf.Name & "'" & _
 " Not Found in ' " & strNewPath & "'"
Case 3321 ' Nothing Entered
 MsgBox "No Database Name Entered"
Case Else
 MsgBox "Uncaptured Error " & Str(Err) & " " & _
 Err.Description
End Select

Set tdf = Nothing
relink = False

'******************Get rid of blank records
DoCmd.SetWarnings False
DoCmd.OpenQuery "Delete_Blank_Material_Records"
DoCmd.SetWarnings True
'********************************************

End Sub

Function TransferBEData(ByVal tSource As String, ByVal tDestination As String)

If FileExists(tDestination) Then
  Kill tDestination
End If

FileCopy tSource, tDestination

End Function
```

Comment: Why is there a vote to close this question?

Comment: The close vote is marked OFF TOPIC, likely because an idiot thinks an Access question is by definition not a programming question.

Answer (score 0):

The reason this doesn't work, is because re-linking the tables to another source will not delete the entry from the .mdw lock file (or security equivalent in later versions than 03). You would need to close your front-end database and then re-open in order to unlock the local .mdb file.